# Thingsboard unrecognized service

Tags: thingsboard

I try to install Thingsboard CE by this install guide "https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/"  but when i want to start the service this message appeare "thingsboard: unrecognized service"

I try many times but always this message appeared. I search the internet but couldn't find any solution to solve this problem, Please help me to solve it